# project hierarchy Idea rather then BlueJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, namespaces, bluej

In some Coursera course the expected IDE is BlueJ. Right from the start, I would like to learn how to manage projects with more advanced IDE, like IntelliJ Idea.

The teacher staff provided their framework which they prebuilt in BlueJ.app env. So they don't tell anything about manual import.

I have their framework downloaded in directory `edu/duke/bunch-of-java-classes` or should I say `edu/duke/*.java.`

On the first line in some class I have `import edu.duke.*;` aside `import java.util.*;`, the 2nd one is ok.

How to harness the power `edu/duke/*.java.`. Where to put it in project hierarchy?

I would like to have them separated. My java classes in, lets say, module1 for week1 and theirs in edu/duke.

Comment: In the source folder, where you put your own java source file(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please download the files courserajava.jar and apache-csv.jar files from the link http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course2/index.php and add them as external libraries in the project created in IntelliJ/Eclipse. The edu.duke libraries can be used in the programs written.

Comment: now they have only zip archive, how to deal with them?

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate on what Prajakta said:

1. Download the JAR files under "Course Code Packages" here: http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/downloads/bluej.php?course=2
2. Add after to your new IntelliJ project as external libraries.

   - Click File in the toolbar
   - Choose Project Structure
   - Select Modules in the left panel
   - In the Dependencies tab, click '+' and choose "JARs or directories."
   - Upload both files
3. Now both import statements will work correctly:
   import edu.duke.*;
   import org.apache.commons.csv.*;